# Using SearchFilter on a property that is a list

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm currently working with EWS on Outlook 2010.  I'm attempting to do a look up on a user's contacts based on the **Categories** field.  I essentially want to return every contact whose category field contains a particular substring.  Below is an example:

```cs
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService
{
    Credentials = new WebCredentials(user, password, domain),
    Url = new Uri(exchangeUrl),
};
string searchString = "abc";
SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Categories, searchString);
ItemView view = new ItemView(200);
Mailbox mailbox = new Mailbox("blah@blah.com");
FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, mailbox);
FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(folderId, filter, view);
```

This of course fails since the **Categories** field is now annoyingly a `StringList` instead of a normal string.  All of our user contacts only have exactly 1 category associated with them.  Is there a way I can get this `SearchFilter` to work by only running the comparison on the *first **Category***?

**PLEASE NOTE**:  For reasons beyond my control, I [cannot use AQS strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266512%28VS.85%29.aspx).  They are simply not an option.  I must use the `SearchFilter` objects (*or some other mechanism to filter results*).

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, you have to use [AQS](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/e297b09d-0a69-4a62-8da1-12084df9265f) or an [Exact Match](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/c94c8cb0-9fd0-4363-ada7-4ea735991f04). If you can't use either, there's always the brute force approach of [using `ItemView` and paging through all messages category properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh148195%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) yourself for a contains implementation.

Comment: It's sad this is the only option...  the ews API is really lacking in some areas